# AS3 Slider Component built in focus rectangle never show again if slider is used once

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

unlike most people that want to completely disable the blue focus rectangle of the different components specially the slider, i want it to be there when focused, the focus rectangle show properly when focusing on the slider programmatically with this code :

```
my_mc_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, Focus_My_Slider_1);
function Focus_My_Slider_1 (event:MouseEvent):void {
stage.focus = My_Slider_1
}

my_mc_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, Focus_My_Slider_2);
function Focus_My_Slider_2 (event:MouseEvent):void {
stage.focus = My_Slider_2
}
```

once you run the program, it works great, unless you use any of the sliders and the blue border is gone, it is gone forever however the sliders are focused but the blue border no more show up unless you press tab key, it bring it back to live.
i tried a lot to find a solution but no luck, and this is my first post here.
hope any one can help.